# Mouse Navigation - dedicated right-click?

Tags: linux, kde

In kde, I'm using mouse navigation to move the mouse pointer with the keyboard. However, it is very cumbersome to right-click as I have to first press "-" to change the click behavior to right click and then press '5' to actually do the right click. Then, if I want to left click, I have to hit '/' to set the click behavior to left click again and press '5' to do the actual click.

Is there a setting to make '-' do the right mouse click right away and not changing the behavior of the '5' button? Ideally, I would like '/' to be immediate left click, '*' to be immediate middle click, and '-' to be the immediate right click without needing to press any other buttons to perform the actual click. Is there a way to do this?